# ProFtpd Homedirectory per user

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I So new to linux Ubuntu and moving from windows.

The problem I have is related to ftp. This is what I am trying to do. 
My websites are located in /var/www. Each website has its own root for examle
/var/www/site1
/var/www/site2

This is what I am trying to do. I would like to have a user for each site (directory) so they can access their home directory through ftp.

Looks so easy, but can't make it work. Any help or direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a user per site you might need to create virtual hosts in apache so that instead of the sites being located in /var/www they will be located in the user's home directory.

You can then allow users to access their home folders via ftp. These are instructions that are  available on the Ubuntu site. Access them [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=79588)

alternatively you can add the users as FTP users with the right permissions to the folders located under /var/www/ . Documented well in the ProFTPd website.

There's an old post [here](http://cviorel.easyblog.ro/2007/09/19/howto-create-a-ftp-server-with-user-access-proftpd/) that you might still find helpful